# How to assign reactive controller variable to textediting controller in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-getx, state-management

I am trying to use DatePicker in flutter and displaying it in textfield. I'm using getx for this purpose since I don't want to make my widget stateful. But I'm getting some kind of error while assigning my controller variable in TextField.

```
var _date = TextEditingController().obs;
DateTime _currentDate = DateTime.now();

Obx(() => TextField(
                    controller: _date,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        focusColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 78, 128, 255),
                        suffixIcon: const Icon(IconlyLight.calendar),
                        hintText: "End Date",
                        hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            borderSide:
                                BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade500))),
                    onTap: () async {
                      DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                          context: context,
                          initialDate: _currentDate,
                          firstDate: _currentDate,
                          lastDate: DateTime(2222));

                      /**if (pickedDate != null) {
                        _date.text = DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(pickedDate);
                      }**/
                    },
                  ),)
```

But I'm getting the following error while doing so:

```
The argument type 'Rx<TextEditingController>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextEditingController?'.
```

What can I do to make it work? or is there any other alternative that I can try except making it stateful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution.

Source code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Rx<TextEditingController> textEditingController = TextEditingController().obs;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Obx(
          () {
            return TextField(
              controller: textEditingController.value,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```